# XCode 5 project with RestKit v0.21.0 won't compile

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, restkit, xcode5

I tried to use RestKit v0.21.0 in my application. I installed RestKit as a Git Submodule following instructions [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule).

Project compiled without errors.

Then i tried to access mainQueueManagedObjectContext:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;

return YES;
```

}

and received error:

```
Receiver 'RKManagedObjectStore' for class message is a forward declaration
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After playing around with commit history i realized that this problem appears after adding `#ifdef _COREDATADEFINES_H` to RestKit project.

Then i found solution [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1564).

You should add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to your PCH file:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

#endif
```

Comment: And very important this order of libraries integration because when I have a different one it shows me error.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Order does matter. Make sure RestKit is at the end.

Comment: your answer didn't help me, but your comment did thank you very much, i've wasted a good 2 hours on this and time is a factor :3